# How to put the system to sleep & again resume from sleep automatically (programatically) without any manual "mouse click or keyboard hit

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, windows-8, sleep

My question is in continuation to my previous question "[SetSuspendState() API never returns in Win8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18123179/setsuspendstate-api-never-returns-in-win8/18123789#18123789)"

I'm running my VC++ code on Win8/Win8.1 m/c.

> My purpose is to put the system to sleep & again bring back the system
>   from sleep automatically without any manual "mouse click or keyboard
>   hit".
>   But I'm not able to achieve "taking the system to sleep and hence ofcourse not bringing the system back from sleep." With the below call SetSuspendState(), the system is going to hibernation always, instead of sleep.

I'm again pasting the code snippet for quick reference::

```
int wait = 100;
LARGE_INTEGER WaitTime;
    WaitTime.QuadPart = wait;
    WaitTime.QuadPart *= -10000000;

HANDLE hTimer = CreateWaitableTimer(NULL, FALSE, NULL);
        if(0 == SetWaitableTimer(hTimer, &WaitTime, 0, NULL, NULL, TRUE))
        {
            res = false;
            return res;
        }
        if(0 == SetSuspendState(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE))
        {
            res = false;
            return res;
        }
```

Here I'm calling "SetSuspendState() API with the options to put the system to sleep & to get it back from sleep automatically but the system is just going to hibernation::

> SetSuspendState(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)

Can anyone kindly help me in solving this problem & how do i put my system to sleep "programatically & resume back from sleep automatically without manual "mouse click or keyboard hit".

Comment: Isn't "sleep" usually a state where no program is running at all?

Comment: @PlasmaHH: Yes, but [Timers can supposedly wake you up](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373235(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: @codeLover: Can I just confirm that the system goes into hibernate rather than sleep?

Comment: @Mats Petersson :: Yes, the system goes to just hibernation rather than sleep. This is evident because, after I execute this API SetSuspendState() the monitor goes off and even after mouse click or keyboard stroke it doesn't come back and it needs a power button press only to come back. And also while resuming back I see the windows boot screen with windows logo, which is seen only during restart or hibernation. Clearly evident that the system is entering hibernation and not sleep.

Comment: So, "there's your problem", as they say. I'm not sure what the exact underlying cause may be in your setup, but clearly you are not asking for hibernation in your call (first BOOL value), so it's "something else is forcing the system to hibernate". Could be a BIOS setting, or even a bug in the BIOS. Or some setting in your power management settings that says "Please hibernate instead of sleep".

Comment: Check to see if you have *hybrid sleep* enabled. From an admin command prompt type `gpedit` and navigate to *Computer Configuration* -> *Administrative Templates* -> *System* -> *Power Management* -> *Sleep Settings*. There will be two policies named *Turn off hybrid sleep*. There are also other settings that may be relevant to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

***Before performing sleep we should make sure that system supports the required sleep state and allow wake up timer should be enabled, use following code to do the same.***

```
//Check support
    SYSTEM_POWER_CAPABILITIES sysPowCab = {0};
    if (CallNtPowerInformation(SystemPowerCapabilities, NULL, 0, &sysPowCab, sizeof(SYSTEM_POWER_CAPABILITIES)) != 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (!sysPowCab.SystemS3)
        {
            return false;
        }
    return true;

//Enable allow wake up timer
    GUID *pPwrGUID;
    GUID subGUID = GUID_SLEEP_SUBGROUP;
    GUID BriGUID = GUID_ALLOW_RTC_WAKE;

    DWORD ret = PowerGetActiveScheme(NULL, &pPwrGUID);
    if (ret != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        return false;
    }

    ret = PowerWriteACValueIndex(NULL, pPwrGUID, &subGUID, &BriGUID, 1);
    if (ret != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
```